# "Только и умел, что переживать" - запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, частица

[§ 41.9](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827524.html)

> Запятая не ставится перед союзом *что* в выражении *только и…что,* за
> которым следует существительное или местоимение: *Только и денег что
> пятак в кармане; Только и всего что рубашка на теле; Только и
> развлечений что кино раз в неделю; Только и свету что в окошке; Только
> и разговоров что о них двоих.*
>
> Но если конструкция, содержащая в первой части сложную частицу *только
> и*, глагол *делать (сделать, знать)* и союз *что*, имеет во второй
> части глагол, то перед *что*  запятая ставится: *С дедушкой они
> только и делали, что  играли в шахматы* (Усп.); *С девяти утра до
> шести вечера  только и знаешь, что  торчишь здесь* (Купр.); *Только и
> делает, что  болтает;  Только и сделал, что  отказался;  Только и
> знает,  что ходит из угла в угол.* Постановка запятой в подобных
> предложениях объясняется тем, что они являются сложными: вторая часть
> с союзом *что* показывает, что ограничивается чья-либо деятельность, а
> сложная частица *только и* в первой части указывает на это
> ограничение.
>
> То же, если вторая часть является придаточной частью
> сложноподчиненного предложения: *Только и нового, что  зайцы
> совещаются, как им орлов прогнать* (Л.Т.).

Где тут мой  случай? У меня сказуемое какое-то распространённое...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая ставится: *Только **и умел, что переживать**.*

**Другие примеры:** Только и умеют, что запрещать! Враги только и умеют, что строить мелки козни. Я же только и умел, что учиться в школе.

Розенталь формально связывает правило **с наличием глагола во второй части**, но объяснить это  можно так.

1) Запятая не ставится, если предложение по структуре соответствует **простому предложению** (союз ЧТО разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое):

*Только и денег что пятак в кармане. Все деньги — это пятак в кармане.*

*Только и развлечений что кино раз в неделю. Все развлечения — это кино раз в неделю.*

2) Запятая ставится, если предложение по структуре соответствует **сложному предложению с придаточным изъяснительным**. (При этом предложение можно перестроить, заменив глагол или союз  близким по значению словом):

*С дедушкой они только и делали, что играли в шахматы. С дедушкой они только и делали **то**, что играли в шахматы.*

*Только и знает, что ходить из угла в угол. (Только и знает, **как** ходить из угла в угол)*.

*Только и умел, что переживать. (Только и **знал**, как переживать).*

Answer (score 0):

Галина, отрезвитесь. Распространенность (а такое явление, кстати, было приведено в примерах к правилу) в данном случае не влияет на смысл. Вот наиболее важная часть (но автор ошибся, выделив только глаголы: "делать", "знать" и "сделать"):

"Но если конструкция, содержащая в первой части сложную частицу "только и", **глагол (близкий по смыслу к данным, я считаю)** **"делать" (сделать, знать)** и союз "что", имеет во второй части **глагол**, то перед что запятая ставится: С дедушкой они только и делали, что играли в шахматы (Усп.); С девяти утра до шести вечера только и знаешь, что торчишь здесь (Купр.); "

Глагол "уметь" во многом подобен глаголу "знать", поэтому следуем данному правилу.
Хочу отметить, что данные глаголы были выбраны **не случайно**. Весь смысл данных предложений сводится к сравнению объекта либо действия, отстраненных от других явлений, с соответствующими объектом или действием.

Ответ: запятая есть (Вот я болван. Всё объяснил, а ответ дал противоположный).